# OpenSSL.net Key generation exception

Tags: c#, .net, openssl, rsa

I am trying to use OpenSSL.net library to generate a public / public key pair for encryption. I added the ManagedOpenSsl.dll to the references and put libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll into my working directory (As described [here](https://github.com/openssl-net/openssl-net/blob/master/README.md))

Unfortunately I get a nasty exception when running the code (it builds fine). What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT code modified:

```
    public void GetKeys ()
    {
        using( OpenSSL.Crypto.RSA test = new OpenSSL.Crypto.RSA() )
        {
            test.GenerateKeys( 1024, 65537, null, null );

            string privKey = test.PrivateKeyAsPEM;
            string pubKey = test.PublicKeyAsPEM;

            MessageBox.Show( privKey, "Private Key" );
            MessageBox.Show( pubKey, "Public Key" );
        }
    }
```

This is the exception error I get says "SystemTypeInitializationException".

Comment: `System.TypeInitializationException` means an exception was thrown in a static constructor. It will contain an inner exception of what that exception was. Your code does not include a static constructor, so nothing looks wrong.

Comment: Also, if `BigNumber.One` is your public exponent, I would strongly recommend you not use this. Use 3 or 65,537.

Comment: Just to be clear, if you use 1 as your public exponent (e), your RSA is broken because recovering d becomes trivial.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am modified the code according to your comments. The exception occurs in the constructor. I suspect it has something to do with where I put the libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll (I added ManagedOpenSsl.dll as ref) but experimenting with that did not solve my problem.
I also rebuild the ManagedOpenSsl.dll project (https://github.com/openssl-net/openssl-net) in Release mode because I realized I had it in Debug mode earlier. But still not solution.

Comment: Also, according to http://openssl-net.sourceforge.net/INSTALL it says "If you're having trouble with the native library being loaded under mono,
try using MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug when invoking mono.". But I could not find any other reference to what 'mono' is.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be the libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll files are not present in the output folder after build. Please check the properties of that files and make sure that "Copy to Output Directory" is marked as "Copy Always". After build process the files must be in x86 or x64 subfolders depending the version of the library which you're using.